# Why do I get invalid num_units_in_tick and time_scale while reading VUI?

Tags: h.264

I'm reading Video usability information and it is correct for all 29.97fps files, but for a 25fps file I'm getting wrong values.

For the `num_units_in_tick` I get 771 and for the `time_scale` I get 3892314307.

The standard makes no difference regarding the fps:

```
if( timing_info_present_flag )
{
    num_units_in_tick                  u (32)
    time_scale                         u (32)
    fixed_frame_rate_flag              u (1)
}
```

Why am I able to read correct values from one file, but not from the other?

Edit:
NALU:

```
00 00 00 01 67 64 00 28 AD 84 3F FF C2 1F FF E1
0F FF F0 87 FF F8 43 FF FC 21 FF FE 10 FF FF FF
FF FF FF FF FF 08 7F FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 2C C5
01 E0 11 3F 78 0A 10 10 10 1F 00 00 03 03 E8 00
00 C3 50 94
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the `emulation byte`. If we take a look at the last 10 bytes, we have:

```
00 00 03 03 E8 00 00 C3 50 94
```

The first 03 is an emulation prevention byte and it should be skipped. Then we have num_units_in_tick = 1000 and time_scale = 50000.